# EmberRoute renderTemplate: with model:

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to have a custom Ember Route, like the following:

```
App.ResultRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
        alert(model);
        this.render('result/main', {
            outlet: 'content',
            controller: controller
        });
    },

    model: function(params) {
        return this.get('store').find('result', params.id).then(function(result) {
            return result;
        })
    },
})
```

However, looks like renderTemplate: doesn't like model:. In other words, I can get into renderTemplate when accessing the route directly, but when I try to implement the model like this it just wont work.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean when you do alert model, you are not getting the result model? You might want to set the model to the controller too, controller.set('model', model) before you set the controller in the render function.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should not use **then**:

```
model: function(params) {
        return this.get('store').find('result', params.id);
  }
```

The find method return a promise object which is used by ember routing process.

I would also recommend to let Ember renderTemplate based on its defaults. You should not normally implement this method in your routes if you follow the conventions.

In your case, App.ResultController must extend Ember.ObjectController.